# Reset CSS3 transforms with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scale, css-transforms

I need to set a css3 transform:scale() back to it's original value.

See this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Z2TNw/

It works on click, but not when I hover out..

I also tried setting to scale(1) but that doesn't help either..

Any ideas?

Comment: For the record, your CSS is missing a `}` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second hover callback, you are still using `inValue`. If you switch it to use `outValue`, like this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z2TNw/1/  It works as expected.